# exec a global variable from an extern module

Tags: python, string, exec, global, python-module

I have an extern module where I want to set "exec" expressions as global (because I need to pass strings as variables names)

So, I have a function like

```
def fct_in_extern_module():
    exec 'A = 42' in globals()
    return None
```

and in my main script I have

```
import extern_module
extern_module.fct_in_extern_module()
```

Thus, why do I have

```
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

While if I do (in the main script)

```
def fct_in_main():
    exec 'B = 42' in globals()

fct_in_main()

>>> B
42
```

Any idea how can I set the string 'A' as a variable name in a extern module ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try `extern_module.A` ? Not sure about that, but it might be the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`globals()` means "the globals dict of **this** module". Thus, the way you have chosen to code `extern_module.py` will *not* affect the globals dict of any other module.

One way to fix: define it as:

```
def fct_in_extern_module(where):
    exec 'A = 42' in where
```

and call it as:

```
extern_module.fct_in_extern_module(globals())
```

Of course, as usual, `exec` is not the best way to solve the problem. Better:

```
def fct_in_extern_module(where):
    where['A'] = 42
```

faster and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

`globals()` always returns the `__dict__` of the module where it was called.  This is really the only reasonable choice ... consider:

```
# qux.py
import foo
foo.bar()

# foo.py
import baz
def bar():
    return baz.exec_stuff()

# baz.py
def exec_stuff():
    exec 'A = 1' in globals()
```

Should the global be set in `qux.py` or `foo.py` or `baz.py`?  Looking at it this way, `baz` is the *most* obvious choice and the one that python uses.

Now that brings us to the question of *why are you using exec in the first place*?  Generally it's a much better idea to *return* the value you need to the caller.  Then they can do what they wish with it:

```
def fn_in_extern_module():
    return 42
```

and then:

```
import extern
A = extern.fn_in_extern_module()
```